# Simplifying nested subscriptions in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two observables

`clients$` is a stream of client connections

`data$` is a stream that delivers data endlessly

Whenever a client connects, I subscribe to `data$` and send it to the client.

I read that nesting subscriptions is a no-go in RxJS, so this approach is probably wrong.

```
const clients$ = createClientStream()
const data$ = Observable.interval(1000).share()

clients$.subscribe(c => {

  const s = data$.subscribe(d => c.send(d))

  c.on('disconnect', () => s.unsubscribe())

})
```

**What is the idiomatic RxJS approach to this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md).

```
const clients$ = createClientStream()
const data$ = Observable.interval(1000).share()

clients$
  .flatMap(c => {
     const disconnect$ = Rx.Observable.create (observer => {
       c.on('disconnect', () => {observer.onNext({}); observer.onCompleted();})
     })
     return data$.takeUntil(disconnect$)
  }, (c,d) => c.send(d))
```

Comment: how does this integrate the disconnect?

Comment: I added the disconnect part.